# Track Custom commits on Read Only git submodule

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules, git-commit

I'm working with Three20 as a git submodule on my iPhone app.  I have a couple custom modifications I've made to the three20 library and would like to commit them such that my project sees the commits.  I don't want, nor can I, commit these changes to the actual three20 repo.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you clone the Three20 repo from github and store it locally, then add as submodule so you have your own local copy you can commit to?

Comment: Or can you fork the repository?

Comment: Fork!  We're going to fork the repo.  Thanks!  (Apparently there's 800 something forks on the three20 repo... go figure :-)

Comment: Nice, glad you got it working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please fork the repository and use that in the submodule. If the submodule points to the main repo, you can change that url in the config of the submodule itself. When you update it now, ensure you don't run `git submodule init` or add the init option to `git submodule update`. This will allow you to work off of a fork instead.

Comment: Nice answer hijack buuuuddy, ... more detail though ;)

Comment: That's more than enough. You have to be weary of the init option/command though.. so no hijacking. Lots of projects have the submodule pointing to another of the authors github repos. If you have a fork, you will point to that and now you can't push up your submodule changes. To keep the .gitmodules file the same, you need to set the alternate url to your fork of the submodule AFTER the init or update with the init option.

Comment: I meant you had more detail buddy than my comment haha ;) but thanks for the more detail p.s. beers soon